# How verify function is working in Cordapp

Tags: corda

I have developed one sample cordapp where I am instantiating the state object inside the InitiatorFlow.

```
BookingState outputState = new BookingState(customerName, customerAge,checkInDate,checkOutDate,roomType,roomRate,bookingAmount,getOurIdentity(),lemonTree);
```

1. Will this statement automatically call the verify method which presents inside the Contract class?
   or Do I need to call the verify method inside the Flow class?
2. Do TransactionBuilder need verify method?
3. Will the below code will collect the signature from counterparty? I am asking because in maximum cases I have seen this code to collect the counterparty signature. (`SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(ptx, session));`)

   ```
   private final ProgressTracker.Step GATHERING_SIGNATURE = new ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature"){
       @Override
       public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
           return CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question in the same order:

1. No, the initiator of the flow must explicitly call the `verify()` function before signing it locally.
2. Same as above.
3. The code that you shared does not collect signatures; it only defines that step in the progress tracker so it prints it out on your node's shell when you run the flow. However calling `CollectSignaturesFlow` will `send` the transaction to all provided counter-parties `FlowSession`, and `receive` back their signatures when they call `SignTransactionFlow` in the responder flow. See an example of calling `CollecSignaturesFlow` [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/62722858a2f50512a9445e1f79b4619d2e8199d0/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L109-L113).

Looking at your code:

1. If you call `CollectSignaturesFlow` in initiator, you must call `SignTransactionFlow` in responder; otherwise your initiator flow will hang, because it has a `receive` (which is called inside `CollectSignaturesFlow`), and that `receive` will wait until a responder flow will `send` something, and in that case the responder must call `SignTransactionFlow` which internally has a `send` to send the signed transaction by the counter-party. See IOU example [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/62722858a2f50512a9445e1f79b4619d2e8199d0/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L134-L151).
2. The reason why your flow still verifies the transaction and throws an error when you supply a faulty one is because you call `FinalityFlow` inside your initiator which implicitly verifies the transaction before notarizing it (see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/6581815ec240eb342df5a2909965c330207559a6/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L161)).

You might ask, why do I need to call `transactionBuilder.verify()` if the notary already does it? Well, why sign the transaction and send it to other parties without verifying it first? You're consuming resources and sending messages between nodes (to send and receive signed transactions); instead, first check whether the transaction is valid or not, then sign it locally and send it to other peers. Btw, counter-parties in responder flow also run the `verify()` method implicitly when they receive the transaction through calling `SignTransactionFlow` (see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/6581815ec240eb342df5a2909965c330207559a6/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/CollectSignaturesFlow.kt#L290)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. Now I am clear with the verify concept. But, I am still confused about the 3rd question.  
Will this below code will collect the counterparty signature?   


private final ProgressTracker.Step GATHERING_SIGNATURE = new ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature"){
    @Override
    public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
        return CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is a sample code snippet to answer your questions.


// 1. This will only create BookingState instance
BookingState outputState = new BookingState(customerName, customerAge,checkInDate,checkOutDate,roomType,roomRate,bookingAmount,getOurIdentity(),lemonTree);

TransactionBuilder transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);
transactionBuilder.addOutputState(outputState);
transactionBuilder.addCommand(new BookingContract.Commands.Issue() ,
ImmutableList.of(issuer.getOwningKey(),owner.getOwningKey()));

//2. You should call the verify method from transactionbuilder class which will //run the verify method of contract class.
transactionBuilder.verify(getServiceHub());

//3. Below code is used to collect signatures from the counterparty
FlowSession session = initiateFlow(owner);

SignedTransaction fullySignedTransaction = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, singletonList(session)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I am not calling the verify method from transactionbuilder class still I am getting an error whenever I am providing some incorrect data. You can check the code from the below GitHub link and also check the counterparty signature part.

[link](https://github.com/arijitmhptr/Hotel-Booking-Cordapp)